# Flutter SFCalender hide today button

Tags: flutter, dart, syncfusion, sfcalendar

I am using the [SFCalender](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_calendar) in my app and it works really well! (kudos to the creators). However there is one thing that annoys me:

[image]

The **Today-Button.**

I don't want it there but I can't find any way to disable it! Also it looks a bit buggy (with the 2 "x" inside) ? Is there any way to disable it? It is also not staying inside the main calenders `bounds`...

Happy for every help here! Could only find [this issue](https://www.syncfusion.com/feedback/34053/provide-support-to-hide-and-show-the-today-icon-button-in-the-flutter-calendar) but no reply from the team so maybe someone from the community can help me out here :)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Query:  Is there a way to hide the Today-Button in the SfCalendar?

We have already considered your requirement as a feature “Provide support to hide and show the Today icon button in the Flutter Calendar (SfCalendar)” and logged feature request for the same. We will implement this feature in any of our upcoming releases.

At the planning stage for every release cycle, we review all open features and identify features for implementation based on specific parameters including product vision, technological feasibility, and customer interest. We will let you know when this feature is implemented. We appreciate your patience until then.

Thank you for requesting this feature. We are always trying to make our products better and feature requests like yours are a key part of our product growth efforts.

You can also communicate with us regarding the open features any time using our Feature Report page.

Feedback link: https://www.syncfusion.com/feedback/34053/provide-support-to-hide-and-show-the-today-icon-button-in-the-flutter-calendar

If you have any more specification/suggestions to the feature request, you can add it as a comment in the portal and cast your vote to make it count.

Comment: a `builder` function with a `jumpToToday` callback would be handy. But for now I can just build that myself. Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score -1):

Seems like param you are looking for is showDatePickerButton in SfCalendar constructor

```
SfCalendar({
...
this.showDatePickerButton = false,
...
})
```

Just remove it or set to false

Comment: nope thats not it. That's just disabling the `datePicker` when tapping the header. But the icon is still there.

Comment: So I've checked how it works internally and there is no direct possibility to disable today button, also I'm really curious where those 'x'es came from.
You may try play with 'isMobilePlatform' and 'isPickerShown' properties along with 'showDatePickerButton'.
If that's no luck, you always can fork their repo and remove it by hands or just copy part of source code.
Still check their licenses first.

Comment: same :D really weird behavior

Comment: As mentioned in other answer try to play with SfDateRangePicker and it's showTodayButton property.

Comment: But how can I do that from within the SFCalender ?

Answer (score -1):

There is a property called `showTodayButton`
you just have to set it to false
`showTodayButton: false`

Comment: u sure? I cant find it. I am using the `SFCalender`.